# Unable to GetItems() from Multilist Field with Search

Tags: solr

I am currently working on upgrading `Sitecore 8.2 to 9.3`, I came across the multi-list field with Search where we were able to get the items in 8.2 but not in 9.3.
Please find the below code used to get the items from Multilist field with Search:

```
 MultilistField refMultilistField = sectionItem.Fields[ISection_DefinitionConstants.Selected_SectionsFieldName];
     if (refMultilistField != null)
     {
         Item[] items = refMultilistField.GetItems();
                        foreach (Item templateSectionItem in items)
                        {
                            TemplateSection templateSection = new TemplateSection();
                            templateSection.TemplateSectionId = templateSectionItem.ID.Guid;
                            templateSection.TemplateSectionName = templateSectionItem.Name;
                            sectionDefination.SelectedSectionItems.Add(templateSection);
                        }
     }
```

In 9.3, the item value is `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item[0]` but we are able to get the items in 8.2.

Could anyone please suggest if there any modifications in Sitecore 9.3 related to the `Multilist with Search` datatype?

Answer (score 0):

When you assign refMultilistField you might try wrapping it in an explicit cast ((MultilistField){your code})

Comment: That explicit cast will happen anyway since `refMultilistField` is explicitly typed as `MultilistField`